# Use case for @EnableZuulServer

Tags: netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I am wondering what use case would be served by `@EnableZuulServer`?

In my case I want to use the ZuulFilter framework for micro-services, and also the spring handlerMappings on Controllers to be called after passing through the Zuul Filter framework. Do not want proxy forwarding.

Is that possible and how? Can we use `@EnableZuulServer` mode for this scenario? I didn't find much documentation to be able to understand how `@EnableZuulServer` would work.

Can someone explain and help?

Answer (score 6):

From the Spring Cloud Netflix documentation:

> Spring Cloud Netflix installs a number of filters based on which
>   annotation was used to enable Zuul. `@EnableZuulProxy` is a superset of
>   `@EnableZuulServer`. In other words, `@EnableZuulProxy` contains all
>   filters installed by `@EnableZuulServer`. The additional filters in the
>   "proxy" enable routing functionality. If you want a "blank" Zuul, you
>   should use `@EnableZuulServer`.

Based on that, the answer to your question is: yes.

You can add the `@EnableZuulServer` annotation and you will not get proxy forwarding but you will still be able to use the `ZuulFilter` framework.

That said, if you're just looking to filter requests and responses, you can use a standard Servlet `Filter` along with a `FilterRegistrationBean`([relevant javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/FilterRegistrationBean.html))

As far as a use case goes, you'd use `@EnableZuulServer` when you need more customized behavior than what is available with `@EnableZuulProxy`.

So, for instance, maybe for debug purposes you want to be able to support a request header that proxies your request to a specified host when the request originates from within a specific IP range.

Answer (score 1):

From the Spring Cloud Netflix documentation:

> In this case the routes into the Zuul server are still specified by
>   configuring "zuul.routes.*", but there is **no service discovery** and **no
>   proxying**, so the **"serviceId"** and **"url"** settings are **ignored**.